# Where condition with integer values return same as ir were a string

Tags: apache-spark-sql

These two queries in SparkSQL return the same value and I don't know why.
Treating the condition attribute as integer or string.

```
select count(*) from  <my_table> where <my_column> = 100 
union all
select count(*) from  <my_table> where <my_column> = '100'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Logical plan it cast string values to int values based on schema refer this  to understand more - https://medium.com/datalex/sparks-logical-and-physical-plans-when-why-how-and-beyond-8cd1947b605a

where column = 0 ............................................and where column = '0'
[image]